# How to join multiple column values into one column while inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID | Name | Address
```

I have a form which looks like this:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address"/>
```

My PHP Code:

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $sql = "Insert into staff(client_name,address) VALUES ('$client_name','$address')";
    $this->db->query($sql);
```

What i want to do is, join the values posted by user into one column.i.e if user types JOHN in Name field and USA in address field.
I want to following in my database table

```
ID | Name | Address
1   | JOHN USA | USA
```

Comment: So you don't know how to concatenate strings? It's done with `.` symbol.

Comment: Just use `'$client_name $address','$address'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $client_name = $_POST['name'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $name = $client_name .' '. $address;
 $sql = "Insert into staff(client_name,address) VALUES ('$name','$address')";
 $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

use thomething like this:

```
$sql = "Insert into staff(client_name,address) VALUES ('$client_name $address','$address')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate your `$_POST['name']` with `$_POST['address']` in `$client_name` before inserting to database. Like this :

```
     $client_name = $_POST['name'] .' '. $_POST['address'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     $sql = "Insert into staff(client_name,address) VALUES ('$client_name','$address')";
     $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$client_name = $name.' | '.$address;
$sql = "Insert into staff(client_name,address) VALUES   ('$client_name','$address')";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode to encode the content and then store it in database field and when you retrieve the value then use json_decode

```
$form_data_json = json_encode( $_POST );
// store $form_data_json in database.

// When you want to get stored data, just fetch it from db. let it be stored in $fetch 
$original_post_array = json_decode( $fetch, true );
```